# Debugging IdentityServer4 data store

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I was looking on where IdentityServer4 stores all the access token and their mapping to the users, but for some reason the documentation doesn't cover this topic. Is it storing it in-memory, or light database, how can i debug it?

I'm using ASP.net Core + Identity Core. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWTs are not to be persisted anywhere. Identityserver uses `PersistedGrantStore` ([in memory by default](http://src/IdentityServer4/src/Stores/InMemory/InMemoryPersistedGrantStore.cs) with optional implementations for EF or REDIS) to keep refresh tokens and reference tokens (when you switch the default jwt token type to reference). You can find more info in [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Creating-Your-Own-IdentityServer4-Storage-Library) article from one of the IdSrv contributors.